# Duplicating a 433 MHz remote control that uses "rolling code"

Tags: remote-control, 433mhz

I'm having a 433.92 MHz standard remote control which uses "rolling code" encoding.

Are other "rolling code" encoding standard remote controls interoperable, or do I need a more detailed description of the "rolling code" (like a chip modal number, for ex. HCS301 / HCS300 / HCS200) and perhaps some other things?

**So the question is: "Does having both remotes with the same chip (for example HSC301) working on the same 433.92MHz frequency, make them compatible with respect to copying (duplicating)?"**

---

After some research my guess would be no, because I guess that different remotes might have different encoding algorithms (algorithms of rolling code progression), which might be proprietary.

Comment: what do you mean by `interoperable`?

Comment: basically that you can copy the code from the original remote to them

Comment: how would you determine the original code?

Comment: there's no such thing as a "standard remote control".

Comment: @jsotola the original coding scheme would be wirelessly transmitted to the remote control copy

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK, but two remote controls, both using HCS301 are compatible and one can be copied to another? Does having both remotes with the same chip makes them compatible with respect to copying?

Comment: copying of what? The eeprom containing all the secrets is unreadable externally, that's even said within the product description on microchip.org .

Comment: Most remote controls have the copying feature. (I'm talking about gate barrier remote controls). For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKNbXi1VBHc The original remote actively takes part in copying.

Comment: Some remotes (especially security related ones) don't have a copy feature.  Instead, a new remote is added to the receiver.  And yet others have no such features so that you're supposed to replace both at once.

Comment: OK. Ill double-check with my vendor.

Comment: The entire purpose of a rolling code is to prevent copying. (More accurately, the entire purpose of a rolling code is to prevent a "code grabber" or "replay attack" where somebody records and replays the same code. But "record and replay the same code" is exactly what copying is.) As Abel said, with rolling codes each unique transmitter must be paired with the receiver; you cannot "copy" an existing transmitter.

Comment: @croraf `the original coding scheme would be wirelessly transmitted to the remote control copy` ... what is transmitted is the end result of the coding theme ... it is the encrypted version of a password ... you have to know the password and the encryption scheme before you can transmit a successful unlock code

Comment: @Mr.Snrub You are misinterpreting things. The purpose of rolling code is to prevent hacking by secretly listening and then replaying the listened sequence. It has nothing to do with copying, and rolling code remotes can be easily copied if the devices support such feature.

Comment: @croraf "listening and then replaying the listened sequence" is *the exact definition* of a "replay attack" and a "code grabber".

Comment: ...and I should add that all transmitters that "copy" do this by simply duplicating the exact code of the transmitter being copied -- in other words "record and replay". See my answer for an explanation of why this doesn't work for rolling codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick overview of why you cannot copy a rolling code, even if they have the same algorithm:

As noted in the comments, a rolling code is designed to prevent someone from breaking in by recording and later replaying a transmit code. The system does this by employing:

- A transmitter that transmits an ever-changing sequence of codes, and
- A receiver that identifies a valid transmitter and *only responds to new codes* from that transmitter.

In practice (in [Keeloq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeeLoq) and similar systems, which to my knowlege means **all** rolling code systems in existence) the code gets changed each time the transmitter is activated, and the receiver keeps track of the last code it received from the transmitter.

For example imagine a rolling code transmitter with code sequence "ABC" -- in other words on the first five activations the transmitter would transmit codes `ABC01`, `ABC02`, `ABC03`, `ABC04`, `ABC05`. After that fifth transmission (assuming it was received by the receiver!) then the receiver would only accept code `ABC06` or later. That's what makes the rolling code resistant to the record-and-replay hack.

Now let's copy our first transmitter (TX1) over to a second transmitter (TX2). We pair them up using the next transmission, code `ABC06` and all seems well. On their next activation each transmitter will transmit code `ABC07`.

Hopefully you already see the problem. If activate TX1, it transmits code `ABC07` and the receiver responds. But the next time I try to activate TX2, it *also* transmits code `ABC07` and so the receiver rejects it as an old code. Maybe if TX2 were activated a few times it would get ahead of TX1 and activate the receiver... but then later on TX1 would need to "catch up" to TX2, and the whole system is... less than good.

So you cannot copy rolling code transmitters because *copying a rolling code transmitter would only work well if you could somehow keep the two transmitters in sync with one another*, and there is no practical way to do this. It is **far** easier to simply pair a second, new rolling code transmitter with the receiver, as Abel mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. I see. Do you perhaps know how is the pairing of the transmitter with the receiver done. Is this usually done by physically connecting the two?

Comment: This basically also means that all rolling code remote device sellers that advertise the copying capability are fake advertises?

Comment: 1. Typically the pairing is done by activating a ["learn mode"](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00662C.pdf) on the receiver. This basically tells the receiver "the next transmitter you hear, add that to your list of valid transmitters".

Comment: 2. I have never heard of a rolling code remote that can copy. Because of the reasons described in my answer, I'd say it's not really possible. Because "learn mode" exists, it's not really necessary either. I haven't seen the literature you describe, but I'll wager that it's not actually a rolling code transmitter; its probably a fixed code transmitter that can inter-operate with a rolling code system. (Yes, that totally defeats the purpose of rolling code in the first place.)

Comment: @Mr. Snrub There are rolling codes...and craptographically secure rolling codes. Most remotes don't use SHA256...and if they did, they'd probably used for bitcoin mining instead of opening garage doors. -- For a ballpark figure: the TV-B-Gone took up to 69 seconds to brute-force all TVs in range. A rolling code garage door receiver using De Bruijn Codes can be brute-forced in 8 seconds (actually transmitting all codes; it would obviously be much faster if only done it in software). -- The question refers to a "rolling code standard",  but there is none. The answer above refers to HCS301.

Comment: @Klaws the problem I describe is unrelated to encryption; it exists whether the code is encrypted or unencrypted; it's fundamental to the nature of how a rolling code functions. It is also entirely unrelated to brute force search. The problem I am describing is that *there is no way to make a receiver behave correctly with two cloned rolling code transmitters*.  (Side note: the code space is way too large -- 2^31 bits -- for brute-force search, and since the code has framing requirements De Bruijn sequences do not help to speed things up.)

Comment: @Mr. Snrub You assume that all rolling codes have a large code space. Enter the 12 bit transmitter (8 bit models are said to exist as well). 4 bits for the ID, 8 bit for the rolling code (which is a De Bruijn sequence). You need to record just 1 transmission to see (a) the 4 bit ID and (b) the current state of the De Bruijn sequence (internal state == observed data word). And brute-force (if ID is known) in 256 attempts guaranteed, 4096 if ID unknown. -- Your answer mentions "[..]to my knowlege means all rolling code systems in existence" - so you just haven't seen the cheapest ones yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  In fact I have consistently used 433.92 rolling code clone remotes to copy other remotes.  Works fine as long as all those cloning are rolling code.  I copy the transmitter used to open the gate but do so out of range of the receiver.  Please don't be telling people it doesn't work because I have cloned dozens of rolling code remotes.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, with a lot of rolling code implmentations. Only very few implmentation you'll encounter "in the wild" are cryptographically secure (and the most popular cryptographically secure rolling code has successfully been broken via a side-channel attack, but we're not talking about that here). Some devices can "learn" a (not cryptographically secure) rolling code by just "listening" to two consecutive transmissions. Others require to select the type of rolling code via dip switches before learning the code via a transimssion. -- I agree that the answer could elaborate more.

Comment: @user354424 make and model please? I am aware of only one "rolling code" transmitter that allows cloning (Chamberlain / LiftMaster / Sears). That remote has two buttons. One button is intended for a shared community gate. That button *can be cloned* but *is not a rolling code*. The other button is intended for an individual's garage. That button is a rolling code and cannot be cloned. Is this maybe the remote you're using?